# is there a way to use animation-list for string?

Tags: android, string, animation

I want to animate array of string using animation - list, is there a way to create a list of string and add ito animation-list.xml in drawables?

```
iv_randomize.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.randomize_image);

        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) tv_randomize.getBackground();

        frameAnimation.start();
```

if this is not allowed what is the EASIET way to do this. Thank you :))

Comment: Ok, what's your exact goal? You want to change a text within some `View` (for example `TextView`)?

Comment: @BartoszLipinski yes

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with animation list.

You can use this instead:

```
TextView mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

String[] animationStrings = new String[]{"first text", "second text", "third text"};
float maxValue = animationStrings.length + 1;
final Animation textAnimation = new Animation() {

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int index = (int) Math.floor(maxValue * interpolatedTime);
        index = index == maxValue ? index - 1 : index;
        mText.setText(animationStrings[index]);
    }
};
//set all the things you need to set on the textAnimation object
mText.startAnimation(textAnimation);
```

*(I was writing that just of the top of my head - without checking - so you might need to correct it a little)*

Comment: do i put the `Text.startAnimation(textAnimation);` inside my oncreate? because the text only prints but does not change and there is no need to `float maxValue = animationStrings.length + 1;` .  `float maxValue = animationStrings.length` will do, it will product an arrayindexbounderrror

Comment: oh i think it is changing but to fast, i will try search around how to delay the animation time. Thank you

Comment: Yep, about the length- you're right. My mistake. You wanna delay the animation or change the frequency?

Comment: yes, is there a way to delay the change in the textView? i tried to print out the string, and it does change but i did not see the "animation" where the textview changed the text inside..

Comment: There is a ['setStarOffset'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long)) of the 'Animation' you can use for setting the delay

Comment: This code must be gotten crash.